# My WebPage Content is different from the MVC Models

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I am Designing a web page which just shows the number of rows in the Database tables. In that way my web page content is different from the my Models. Now come to my Question that should I build A new model that just contains the number of rows of each table should I just grab all the data then Count. What should I do if my web page content is different from my MVC models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your page will only show the number of rows from a table, your model should be a int and nothing else. It will be better if you do this count in a sql query, to avoid unnecessary traffic of data between your db and your application.

*What should I do if my web page content is different from my MVC models?*

As any developer question, this one has many answers. I'll be happy to answer that if I have more information about what what kind of difference you are talking about.

But... in most cases you can create a new model (you can call it as ViewModel) that matches the exact content your web page needs.